# Why does Pandora appear to be so close to Earth even though it is light-years away?

Tags: avatar-the-way-of-water

If Pandora is a fictional moon in the Alpha Centauri star system, which is located
[**4.37 light-years** away](https://www.justjared.com/2022/12/20/where-is-pandora-in-avatar-how-far-from-earth-is-it/)
from Earth, then why does Pandora look so close to the Earth in this scene from *Avatar The Way of Water?*

[image]

Why does Pandora appear to be so close to Earth even though it is light-years away?

Comment: I think that's Pandora and the planet it orbits...

Comment: That's not earth.

Comment: @A.bakker - That's no space station, it's a moon.

Comment: Polyphemus looks like Jupiter got flipped and colored...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The image does not show Earth and Pandora. It shows Pandora in orbit around the gas giant [Polyphemus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictional_universe_of_Avatar#:%7E:text=In%20the%20film%2C%20Pandora%20is,the%20Polyphemus%20of%20Greek%20mythology.)

> In the film, Pandora is depicted as being located in the Alpha Centauri A system, about 4.37 light-years (276,000 AU) from Earth. It is one of the many natural satellites orbiting the gas giant Polyphemus, named for the Polyphemus of Greek mythology.

Comment: Does it bother anyone else that instead being called Epimetheus or something like that, the planet is named after a completely unrelated cyclops from a completely different mythic age who never met Pandora?